# Are there standardized translations of Unicode character names?

Tags: unicode, internationalization, translation

Every codepoint in the Unicode standard has a unique English name attached to it. I need translations for these names (for a small subset of codepoints) to languages like German, French, Japanese, ... I do have access to professional translators, so it is of course possible to have those names translated one by one, but the result is not necessarily a good representation of the intention of the Unicode standard. I wonder if the Unicode committee has already made an effort to standardize the codepoint names for languages other than English, so that I could simply refer to their translations? I could not find anything but English on unicode.org, but I still hope I missed something. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`.NET` / PowerShell** example: `[Microsofts.CharMap.UName]::Get('č')`

**Windows OS**: there are localized Unicode properties (`name`, at least) saved in *localized* library `getuname.dll`. Use the following script directly, or get inspiration there:

```
<#
Origin   by: http://poshcode.org/5234
Improved by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz

Use this like this: "ábč",([char]'x'),0xBF | Get-CharInfo

Activate dot-sourced like this (apply a real path instead of .\):

. .\_get-CharInfo_1.1.ps1

#>

Set-StrictMode -Version latest

Add-Type -Name UName -Namespace Microsofts.CharMap -MemberDefinition $(
    switch ("$([System.Environment]::SystemDirectory -replace 
                '\\', '\\')\\getuname.dll") {
    {Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Leaf} {@"
[DllImport("${_}", ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=true)]
private static extern int GetUName(ushort wCharCode, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder buf);

public static string Get(char ch) {
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(300);
    UName.GetUName(ch, sb);
    return sb.ToString();
}
"@
    }
    default {'public static string Get(char ch) { return "???"; }'}
    })

function Get-CharInfo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject],[System.Array])]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $InputObject
    )
    begin {
        function out {
            param(
                [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true )] $ch,
                [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false)]$nil=''
                 )
            if (0 -le $ch -and 0xFFFF -ge $ch) {
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Char = [char]$ch
                    CodePoint = 'U+{0:X4}' -f $ch
                    Category = [System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($ch)
                    Description = [Microsofts.CharMap.UName]::Get($ch)
                }
            } elseif (0 -le $ch -and 0x10FFFF -ge $ch) {
                $s = [char]::ConvertFromUtf32($ch)
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Char = $s
                    CodePoint = 'U+{0:X}' -f $ch
                    Category = [System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($s, 0)
                    Description = '???' + $nil
                }
            } else {
                Write-Warning ('Character U+{0:X} is out of range' -f $ch)
            }
        }
    }
    process {
        if ($PSBoundParameters['Verbose']) {
            Write-Warning "InputObject type = $($InputObject.GetType().Name)"}
        if ($null -cne ($InputObject -as [char])) {
            #Write-Verbose "A $([char]$InputObject) InputObject character"
            out $([int][char]$InputObject) ''
        } elseif ($InputObject -isnot [string] -and $null -cne ($InputObject -as [int])) {
            #Write-Verbose "B $InputObject InputObject"
            out $([int]$InputObject) ''
        } else {
            $InputObject = [string]$InputObject
            #Write-Verbose "C $InputObject InputObject.Length $($InputObject.Length)"
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $InputObject.Length; ++$i) {
                if (  [char]::IsHighSurrogate($InputObject[$i]) -and 
                      (1+$i) -lt $InputObject.Length -and 
                      [char]::IsLowSurrogate($InputObject[$i+1])) {
                    $aux = ' 0x{0:x4},0x{1:x4}' -f [int]$InputObject[$i], 
                                                   [int]$InputObject[$i+1]
                    Write-Verbose "surrogate pair $aux at position $i" 
                    out $([char]::ConvertToUtf32($InputObject[$i], $InputObject[1+$i])) $aux
                    $i++
                } else {
                    out $([int][char]$InputObject[$i]) ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example**:

```
PS D:\PShell> "ábč",([char]'x'),0xBF | Get-CharInfo

Char CodePoint         Category Description                    
---- ---------         -------- -----------                    
   á U+00E1     LowercaseLetter Latin Small Letter A With Acute
   b U+0062     LowercaseLetter Latin Small Letter B           
   č U+010D     LowercaseLetter Latin Small Letter C With Caron
   x U+0078     LowercaseLetter Latin Small Letter X           
   ¿ U+00BF    OtherPunctuation Inverted Question Mark         

PS D:\PShell> Get-Content .\DataFiles\getcharinfoczech.txt

Char CodePoint         Category Description                               
---- ---------         -------- -----------                               
   á U+00E1     LowercaseLetter Malé písmeno latinky a s čárkou nad vpravo
   b U+0062     LowercaseLetter Malé písmeno latinky b                    
   č U+010D     LowercaseLetter Malé písmeno latinky c s háčkem           
   x U+0078     LowercaseLetter Malé písmeno latinky x                    
   ¿ U+00BF    OtherPunctuation Znak obráceného otazníku                  

PS D:\PShell>
```

Note that the latter (semi-localized) output comes from the following code (run on the same computer under localized user):

```
"ábč",([char]'x'),0xBF | Get-CharInfo | Out-File .\DataFiles\getcharinfoczech.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://old.reddit.com/r/Unicode/comments/b8zzq6/are_unicode_names_only_in_english_or_are_there/), there were official French translations for a time, but not anymore.